# jQuery selector using data-value attribute with double quotes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm learning UI automated testing and I've been trying to locate this element

```
<a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{"stringVal":"date-desc-rank"}" id="s-result-sort-select_4" class="a-dropdown-link">Release Date</a>
```

on the web page using its "data-value" attribute.

But when I run the following:

```
$('a[data-value="{"stringVal":"date-desc-rank"}"]')
```

it returns an error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Document.querySelector: 'a[data-value="{"stringVal":"date-desc-rank"}"]' is not a valid selector

I've also tried to escape double quotes with backslash symbols with no result.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Easiest solution, so long as you have browser support, is to use a template literal for the string, and then you can use both single and double quotes in the selector.

Comment: Or use the `id` or `class` instead.

Comment: The anchor will end up as `<a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{" stringval":"date-desc-rank"}"="" id="s-result-sort-select_4" class="a-dropdown-link">Release Date</a>` in the actual DOM.

Comment: $('a[data-value=\'{"stringVal":"date-desc-rank"}"\']')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the correct selector has been found:

```
$("a[data-value='{\"stringVal\":\"date-desc-rank\"}']")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quotes in the html to wrap the json and use escaped quotes in the jQuery selector.

Another approach is use `$('a[data-value]').filter(function)` and check the data in the callback. When a data attribute contains valid json, jQuery `data()` will automatically parse it to object/array for you.

```js
// this version changes the text
$('a[data-value=\'{"stringVal":"date-desc-rank"}\']').text('Inserted text');

// this version changes the color
$('a[data-value]').filter(function(){  
   return $(this).data('value').stringVal === "date-desc-rank"
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value='{"stringVal":"date-desc-rank"}' id="s-result-sort-select_4" class="a-dropdown-link">Release Date</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I can't alter element's attributes and can only work with the given selector as it is. So, sadly,  I can't "use single quotes in the html to wrap the json"
@charlietfl

Comment: Well if quotes are as shown in question in the html it will break the attributes for that element when dom parser tries to evaluate them. Inspect in browser dev tools element inspector nd see if they are intact there

Answer (score 0):

I use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode stuff when I want to store it in `data-`

And I have some prototypes on the String object to simplify the process.

```
String.prototype.encode = function() { return encodeURIComponent(this).replace(/'/g,'%27');};
String.prototype.decode = function() { return decodeURIComponent(this); };

`{"stringVal":"date-desc-rank"}`.encode(); //%7B%22stringVal%22%3A%22date-desc-rank%22%7D

<a data-value="%7B%22stringVal%22%3A%22date-desc-rank%22%7D">Release Date</a>
```

Side note for the other answer here, you can also use the attribute right in the selector, no need to filter.

```
$(`a[data-value="%7B%22stringVal%22%3A%22date-desc-rank%22%7D"]`).css('color', 'red');
```

Although you may want to consider using a simpler attribute for selectors, rather than an entire stringified object.

Comment: > Although you may want to consider using a simpler attribute for selectors, rather than an entire stringified object.

Other attributes, such as id or class are more likely to change which makes my test less reliable. I'm using data-* attributes as recommended in Cypress.io documentation.

@PoorlyWrittenCode

Comment: No idea what that is. But what I'm suggesting is, rather than `data-value="stringified object"`, you could do something like `data-string-val="date-desc-rank"`. That way you don't have to worry about storing characters that will break the DOM.